# Metamask deep link for adding custom RPC

Tags: metamask

I noticed the Metamask deep link generator offers the possibility to create payment requests or Dapp launches, which are executed through the Metamask app on mobile devices.

I would like to create a mobile deep link which suggests adding a custom RPC to the Metamask mobile application, but I can't find the proper way to construct this link.

According to Github (https://github.com/MetaMask/metamask-mobile/issues/74) it should be possible.

Does anyone have an idea of what the syntax of this deep link should look like?

Comment: Have you find a solution how to prepare uri to add new rpc to mm app?